# Html Search form to submit query to external site, and see the results

Tags: html, forms

I would like to be able to type a search phrase into an input box, click send, and have a tab open to a new site where the address is something like https://www.w3schools.com/?q=SEARCH_PHRASE. Is there a way to provide this functionality, and show results on the external url. I tried the below code

```
<form method=get action="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">
<input type=text name=q value="">
<input type=submit value="go">
</form>
```

and I end up in the index page, not results, any help?

Comment: You can change the value of the action using some JS when the user enters a value in the input. Give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To present a list of search results, code running on the server has to parse the URL and perform the search.

`http://www.w3schools.com` doesn't pay any attention to the query string. (It has a search form, but it processes it with JS and not with a regular form submission).

`https://duckduckgo.com` **does** pay attention to the query string, so

```
<form method=get action="https://duckduckgo.com/" target="_blank">
  <input type=text name=q value="">
  <input type=submit value="go">
</form>
```

… would work.

You can't make an arbitrary third-party page pay attention to the query string.

Comment: It worked on the www.duckduckgo.com, any suggestion on the code to add some JS in order to parse the input query to the external URL.

Comment: It would be a major security problem if you could execute JS on third party websites.

Comment: This is noted, but this will be execute on my site that is under development. Thanks @Quentin

Comment: Your question seems pretty clear about wanting to execute it on W3School's site. You were explicit about the URL being external. If it was on your site then it wouldn't be external.